# adjusting the insert into SQL

Tags: sql, insert-into

I got this already working;

```
    INSERT INTO TermsFinal 
            (old_classification, count, new_classification, old_term,new_term) 
        SELECT  old_classification   , Count(seed) AS count , new_classification, old_term, new_term FROM   TermsTemp
            GROUP  BY old_classification
            ORDER  BY count DESC
```

There is one more field in the TermsFinal called SOURCE_TABLE which TermsTemp does not have. 
I would like to populate that field too. I already got the $source_table value. I tried this but dis not work.

```
    INSERT INTO TermsFinal 
            (SOURCE_TABLE,old_classification, count, new_classification, old_term,new_term) 
    '{$SOURCE_TABLE}',  SELECT  old_classification   , Count(seed) AS count , new_classification, old_term, new_term FROM   TermsTemp_TEMP
            GROUP  BY old_classification
            ORDER  BY count DESC
```

How do you add that value into the SOURCE_TABLE field of the TermsFinal while executing the insert into statement in  one go?

and the other puzzling thing to me here, how come my first SQL insertinto works without the SQL keyword VALUES. This page http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp teaches that **VALUES** part is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put string (or any other type ) constant into select, for example 
`select 'string' as const_str , field1 from table1` will return 2 columns , the first will have "string" text for all rows. In your case you can do

```
 INSERT INTO TermsFinal 
        (SOURCE_TABLE,old_classification, count, new_classification, old_term,new_term) 
  SELECT  '{$SOURCE_TABLE}', old_classification   , Count(seed) AS count , new_classification, old_term, new_term FROM   TermsTemp_TEMP
        GROUP  BY old_classification
        ORDER  BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to insert data into a table

**One row at a time.** This is where you need the values keyword.

```
Insert into TableA (Col1, Col2,...) values (@Val1, @Val2,...)
```

You can get the id using select @@identity (at least in ms sql), if you have auto identity 
on. This is useful when you need the ID for you next insert.

**From select** (what you're doing)

```
Insert into tableA (Col1, Col2)
Select Val1, Val2 from TableB
```

or insert a hard coded value and values from two separate tables

```
Insert into tableA (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
Select 'hard coded value', b.Val1, b.Val2, c.Val1 
from TableB b join Table c on b.TableCID=c.ID
```

Now you can insert more than one row at once.

**Select into**

This method ends up creating a new table from a query, and is great for quick backups of a table, or part of a table.

```
select * into TermsFinal_backup from TermsFinal where ...
```